# GDB expressions not working. libcc1 image not found

Tags: debugging, gdb, osx-elcapitan

I installed GDB through Homebrew for Mac, and I'm currently using GDB Version 7.10. I set a breakpoint inside an application, and when it finally stopped I tried executing an expression from GDB. Here's what I experienced:

```
(gdb) expr -- hasValue = YES
Could not load libcc1.so: dlopen(libcc1.so, 2): image not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `compile` feature in gdb, then you also need the correct version of GCC and the `libcc1` plugin (which is part of the GCC source tree and is built alongside GCC).

It sounds like you don't have that.

A simpler way to evaluate expressions in gdb is to use `print` (or one of its aliases, like `set variable`).  So for example:

```
(gdb) print hasValue = YES
```

This approach relies on gdb's built-in expression parser and doesn't require any external library or compiler.